# Windows Phone dev - issues re-adding multi language resource files

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone solution that was working fine.  It had a couple of multi language resource files in a project  that included all my shareable code.
However this project was incorrectly created as a Silverlight library, and I am now re-adding the classes etc back in as Windows Phone Class Library.

All good copying the files over .. except for the resource files.  I ended up  re-adding these manually and pasting the data in ... so I now have my AppResource.resx and AppResource.es-ES.resx okay.

But the code that uses them now gets an error that I cannot fathom.

Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'TimetableCommon.AppResource' is less accessible than property 'TimetableCommon.LocalisedStrings.Localisedresources'

The code is 
    namespace TimetableCommon
{
    public class LocalisedStrings
    {

```
    public LocalisedStrings()
    {

    }

    private static TimetableCommon.AppResource localisedresources = new TimetableCommon.AppResource();

    public TimetableCommon.AppResource Localisedresources { get { return localisedresources; } }

}
```

}

Really lost with this... Only difference from the working version seems to me that the Spanish Resource file that I have recreated  does not have the designer class underneath it.  Not sure why.. and I don't think that's the problem here?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok... pretty dumb on my part.

In the resource files there is an access modifier combo box at the top that I had forgotten to  alter.
I think I may have had the same problem first time around.